# Cepstrum calculation with 5-smoothing zero padding

Tags: fft, python, ifft, zero-padding, cepstral-analysis

I am trying to compute cepstrum of a signal x

An implementation of this in python is:

```
x_fft = np.fft.fft(x)
cepstrum = np.real(np.fft.ifft(np.log(abs(x_fft))))
cepstrum = cepstrum[0:len(audio_signal_frame) // 2]  #
cepstrum_db = 10 * np.log10(cepstrum ** 2)
```

I wanted to zero pad x to [hamming number length](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.next_fast_len.html#scipy.fftpack.next_fast_len) before the cepstrum calculation to make the fft more efficient, i.e.:

```
x_padded = zeros(fftpack.next_fast_len(len(x)))
x_padded[0:len(x)] = x
x_fft = np.fft.fft(x_padded)
...rest of the cepstrum calculation...
```

However I am worried that this will affect the ifft in unintended ways (besides changing the quefrency resolution by the padded amount)

Looking at the Interpolated Cepstrum Estimation section of this [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4630216/) it seems that there is an additional step 6 where they pad the fft signal by power of 2. However I am not sure if this step is required or how to implement if padding isn't in powers of 2 since hamming number is not strictly K power of 2.

Comment: Seriously, I very much doubt that the speed difference of the unpadded FFT to your padded FFT matters measurably (unless the unpadded length is a product of primes > 13), so simply don't do that without having a benchmark that actually proves you're doing something good.

Comment: @Marcus Müller I am processing a lot of files and I ran a similar algorithm that uses just the fft and zero padding with hamming number had a significant speed/memory boost compared to zero padding with power of 2 zeros, and both had significant difference compared to no padding. 


My only problem is that I am not sure if just zero padding the original signal would be an issue if I need to take an ifft afterward.

Comment: well, I presume your not directly doing zeropad -> FFT -> IFFT -> throw away zeros but will actually do something with your frequency domain (probably, logarithms?) and that will indeed have an interaction with your zero padding. If speed is such an issue to you, try fftw instead of fftpack (== numpy.fft); it's typically a tad faster for non-power-of-2 transforms. (You might also want to start thinking about the calling overhead from python when you do that.) I tend to work in the high kilotransforms-per-second to megatransforms-per-second regime, and honestly, the overhead of zero padding…

Comment: … (i.e. copying and/or memory reallocation) if you're not filling pre-allocated buffers with the non-zero data is usually worse than the loss you get for small-prime-factor lengths (what **are** your lengths, by the way?).

Comment: In this case the length is a variable since we are taking a frame of speech data that is dependent on the pitch of the speaker. I will look into fftw, thank you for the suggestion, however I would like to have a better understanding on how to zeropad (non-power-of-2 amount) while still making sure FFT -> IFFT is accurate. Do you happen to know any resources that I can read up on this? Thank you for the replys.

Comment: I have ran a memory and time profiler and the bottleneck seems to be the FFT operation.

Comment: as said, the problems depend on what you do between FFT and IFFT; I don't know what you do there! In which order of magnitude are your lengths? It's a tad unusual to have completely variable lengths when processing signals.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't really clear on that. I essentially take the log of the absolute of the FFT signal before applying the IFFT. It's part of how cepstrum is calculated. we fix the number of periodic excitation of a speakers vocal cords (which is dependent on the speakers natural pitch).

Comment: Hm, that'd be basically the diskrete Fourier transform of the cyclic autocorrelation; you'd shift the periodicity of the cyclic part by zero-padding, but that would only have the frequency-resampling effect that you already describe.